# A comma after well

Tags: commas

In the headline "Dread working out? Well we love it!"  Isn't there a comma after "well"?  Shouldn't it read "Well, we love it!"

Comment: If he means: *We love it well*, then there is no comma.

Comment: It doesn't, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Michael Swan's examples of sentences beginning with *well* as a discourse marker (*Practical English Usage*, 2005. 143-15), he always puts a comma after the word. So do I.